# Java - How to filter on value (List)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I will try explain as the best I can.
Let's imagine I've this class:

```
public class Student {
    public String nome;
    public int number;
    public int age;
    public int grade;
}
```

Now I will have an map defined like:

```
Map<String, Student> students;
```

I will want to find the students with grade >= 10 and I did something like this:

```
public List<Student> grade() {
  return students.values()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(Student::verifyGrade)
                 .map(Student::clone)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here's come the 1st problem:
- I'm getting error "incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R" on .map(Student::clone).

2nd problem:
Now if I've my map defined something like: (It's just a example I was thinking), how I would filter with the same style on 1st?

```
Map<String, List<Student> >
```

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: `Student::clone` returns an `Object`, not a `Student`.

Comment: What is the key of your desired result map?

Comment: @Eran since `clone()` can only be called if overridden by `Student`, we can’t say whether it returns `Object` or something else. It could return *anything*. The absence of `implements Cloneable` at the class `Student` suggests that it is not even delegating to `Object.clone()` at all. But whatever it returns, it isn’t any reason for the compiler to complain at `.map(Student::clone)`, as there is no restriction regarding what the mapping function returns.

Answer (score 1):

First problem you don't need to use `map(Student::clone)` after `filter` :

```
return students.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(Student::verifyGrade)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Second problem if the Map is like `Map<String, List<Student>>` you ca use `flatMap` like so :

```
return students.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(Student::verifyGrade)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Well, _if_ the author of the `grade` method is cautious about users modifying the objects in the `List<Student>` returned then it would be wise to clone the `Student` objects. Whether this is really necessary depends on what the OP was thinking when they decided to use `.map(Student::clone)`.

Comment: Hey sir, thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot in fact :)

Answer (score 1):

if all you want to do is *filter* then you don't need `.map(Student::clone)` but if you do need to clone the objects then read on.

`Object::clone` returns a type `Object` hence the compilation error,  there is a workaround by casting the returned `Object` to a type `Person` but instead, I would simply create a copy constructor or a method which copies the content of `Student` into a new instance and returns it.

Then simply do:

```
.map(Student::new) // assuming you have a constructor public Student(Student s){...}
```

or

```
.map(Student::copy) // assuming you have a method public static Student copy(Student s){...}
```

to answer your second question:

```
List<Student> resultSet = 
           myMap.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .filter(Student::verifyGrade)
                .map(Student::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you don't need to clone the `Student` objects then just remove the call to
`.map(Student::new)`.

Comment: didn't `Student::new` just create a class with default values?

Comment: @dehasi no, as stated in my answer if you have a copy constructor as such `Student(Student s){...}` then `.map(Student::new)` is the same as `.map(s -> new Student(s))`.